# Match regular expression for the pattern dddG-xyz

Tags: c#, regex

My try:

```
string exp1 = "\\d+G-";
string z = Regex.Match("CN=314G-VK1,OU=Grupper,OU=314,OU=Skole,OU=03Skien,DC=login,DC=sk-asp,DC=no",exp1).Value;
Console.WriteLine(z);
```

I want to match **314G-VK1** from the string **z**.

Where,

**314** is decimal and it can be any number of digit. say *125632588*.

**G-** is constant.

And **VK1** can be character or decimal but length will be only 3, say *er5*.

How can i meet the requirements?

From my code i only get output **314G-**. I tried several ways but that don't help me anymore.

Comment: It really doesn't seem like you have put much effort into this. You say you have tried several ways. You should edit your question and include what you have tried so we can see what your issue is.

Comment: I tried almost 3 hours. Anyway i got my solution. Thanks everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
string exp1 = @"\d+G-\w{3}";
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cd%2BG-%5Cw%7B3%7D&i=CN%3D314G-VK1%2COU%3DGrupper%2COU%3D314%2COU%3DSkole%2COU%3D03Skien%2CDC%3Dlogin%2CDC%3Dsk-asp%2CDC%3Dno)

The `\w{3}` pattern will match 3 word chars, i.e. mostly letters, digits, underscores. You may precise it if need be, e.g. to only match 3 uppercase ASCII letters or digits, you may use `[A-Z0-9]{3}`. To also include lowercase  letters, add them to the character class, `[A-Za-z0-9]{3}`.

[Regulex regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cd%2BG-%5Cw%7B3%7D):

[image]

.NET regex test results:

[image]

[C# code demo](https://ideone.com/r4ruV7):

```
string exp1 = @"\d+G-\w{3}";
string s = "CN=314G-VK1,OU=Grupper,OU=314,OU=Skole,OU=03Skien,DC=login,DC=sk-asp,DC=no";
string z = Regex.Match(s, exp1)?.Value;
Console.WriteLine(z); // => 314G-VK1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost correct but, you just need to add `[0-9a-zA-Z]{3}` after **G-**.

```
string exp1 = "\\d+G-[0-9a-zA-Z]{3}";
string z = Regex.Match("CN=314G-VK1,OU=Grupper,OU=314,OU=Skole,OU=03Skien,DC=login,DC=sk-asp,DC=no", exp1).Value;
Console.WriteLine(z);
```

Check demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jmHF7z)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
string exp1 = @"\d+G-[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}"

[a-zA-Z0-9]{3} will match with 3-char alphanumeric string.